# react-bingmaps infobox not showing images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bing-maps

I am using react-Bingmaps to show map of location and infobox with shop photo. Everything works well except image, he doesn't load. File path is correct so where is problem in my code?

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactBingmaps } from 'react-bingmaps';

class Map extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div className={'map'}>
                <ReactBingmaps 
                    bingmapKey='deleted_key'
                    center={[54.73695, 25.21741]}
                    zoom={15}
                    pushPins={[{
                        'location': [54.73695, 25.21741],
                        'option': {color: 'black'}
                    }]}
                    infoboxes={[{
                        'location': [54.73695, 25.21741],
                        'option': {
                            title: 'deleted_title',
                            description: "<img src={require('./media/shop-small.svg')} alt='Parduotuvės nuotrauka' />"
                        }
                    }]}
                >

                </ReactBingmaps>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Map;
```

Comment: What is the error shown at console?

Comment: console is clear, but I noticed that in network link to photo is transformed to this http://localhost:3000/%7Brequire('./media/shop-small.jpg')%7D